# Python file counter script not working correctly

Tags: python, file, count

Why does 'cycleNumber' not count above 10?

[image]

```
import os

cycleNumber = 1
for files in os.listdir('Cycles'):
    if files.startswith('Cycle' + str(cycleNumber)):
        cycleNumber += 1
```

Comment: Because the list returned by `os.listdir()` is not sorted numerically as you think.

Comment: In these kinds of situations put some print statements in to see what data you are dealing with. In this case the print would go in between the for and the if.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only iterating over the list returned from `os.listdir()` (which is not in any particular order) once. This means that if the files were given in an unexpected order such as:

```
Cycle2.txt
Cycle1.txt
```

Then it would take till the second iteration for the `cycleNumber` to increment from `1` to `2`, but by then you have already gone passes `Cycle2.txt`!

---

Instead, you should use a while loop:

```
import os
cycleNumber = 0
while any(f.startswith('Cycle' + str(cycleNumber+1)) for f in os.listdir('Cycles')):
    cycleNumber += 1
```

---

A test:

```
$ mkdir Cycles
$ for i in {1..11}; do touch Cycles/Cycle$i.txt; done;
$ python -q
>>> import os
>>> cycleNumber = 0
>>> while any(f.startswith('Cycle' + str(cycleNumber+1)) for f in os.listdir('Cycles')):
...     cycleNumber += 1
... 
>>> cycleNumber
11
```